# When are 'one liners' useful?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

I've seen a few cases on answers, where people offer up 'one liners' as an answer. By which I mean - someone's taken the question offered, and supplied a very concise and compact (correct) answer.

As an example, I would offer: 
[Custom sorting of file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804784/custom-sorting-of-file-names/26805062)

My feeling is - that this hasn't helped particularly. The phrase we've used around our office is 'strafing run' - where someone's come flying past, blown up our obstacle, and flown off into the sunset - the obstacle is removed, but yet we're not any better placed to deal with it next time.

My question is therefore this: Under what circumstances would you consider a 'one liner' a good or bad answer? 
Is there any call to expand 'how to answer' to cover clarity of code?

Comment: For perl and similar scripting languages, oneliners are useful as you can easily invoke them from within bash scripts - as demonstrated by the answer you linked, which could be copypasted into a shell script as is.

Answer (score 9):

A one liner is good if it answers the question in one line.

Comment: (See what I did there?)

Comment: Hmm, but if I ask 'how do I do X?' and you supply me with (in Perl's inimitable style) a some line noise that happens to do the trick... I've got an answer, but no deeper understanding.

Comment: @Sobrique A one liner can be a good answer, but can never really be a great answer. One-liners can give the solution to the problem but can't explain the problem more.

Answer (score 3):

> Under what circumstances would you consider a 'one liner' a good or bad answer?

It is completely dependent on the situation. Someone posts a complicated and unnecessarily long piece of code, with gobs of explanations explaining the complicated code. Someone else posts a single line of code, without explanation, but which is clear as day to someone with working knowledge of the technology involved. (By "clear as day" I don't mean people *already* knew the solution but that it is clear what the solution is doing even if it does not come with an explanation.) Why would the one-liner not be better than the unnecessarily complicated code. (And yes, this happens.)

On the other hand if someone posts a one-liner without explanation that relies on obscure features of the language, and someone else posts longer code which effectively "unpacks" what the one-liner is doing, I'd be inclined to prefer the latter. At the same time, I would not declare the one-liner "a bad answer" unless it has some other significant flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I find typically that one-liners are good in that they're concise and often use features that you're unaware of, but can be difficult to understand. I always prefer readability and maintainability in my code and I don't think 1 liners always fit the bill.

Regarding an answer, if the amount of code/functions in the 1 liner isn't negligable I'd expect a breakdown of each part of the function and explain what it does. I can't find a great example but this one from codegolf https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41365 illustrates what I mean.