# Testing the one liner policy

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Following my post, [Google one liner questions with no SO answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366247/google-one-liner-questions-with-no-so-answer), and I see now [When are 'one liners' useful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276475/when-are-one-liners-useful),  I found what I think is a good test case. Results were marginally towards a positive response in the meta questions (as in, answer these one liner questions!) but I want to test this:

[What is SELECT generator in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117612/what-is-select-generator-in-hibernate)

I am no expert on this `hibernate`, so I do not want to close/dv. There are no duplicates I can find (sql and the like included - **this is way more basic than anything** I could find). The answer is the second search on Google or so (basically my comment). So, my question is, do we want this as a Q and A on the site?

Comment: I'm taking downvotes to mean don't answer (and vice versa for up vote). If this is not your intention please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd argue "no".  The user expects us to teach them thing about this technology instead of making the effort to research it on their own.  These kinds of questions have historically been low-quality and have required a dense amount of information, especially since an open-ended question like that - "what is SELECT in Hibernate" - then opens concerns about knowing what a SELECT statement is in general SQL, or what an ORM layer is.

There's a line in the sand we have to draw sometimes; sometimes a question really is  *too* basic.  Fortunately, this one is *also* too broad and would likely be closed as such.

Comment: Good answer. I am still looking for the line, but I think if "too broad" is a possibility that  is a good indication. Would be easier if the sand was concrete (pun intended).